# Defining Java Generic Type at Class Declaration

Tags: java, generics

I Have

```
public class SongListView<T>  extends ListView<T>
```

How Can I specify that the Generic Type T is to be a Song Object  and no other object?

Comment: `public class SongListView extends ListView<Song>`

Comment: Could still be a subclass of `Song`, unless `Song` is a `final` class.

Comment: @Andreas, this is unavoidable. Any object whose type is subclass of Song, is at the same time a Song, and so can be inserted in ListView<Song>.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov if you don't write `SongListView<T extends Song>` you can add any `class Foo extends Song` but you cannot write (eg) `Foo foo = myList.get(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SongListView extends ListView<Song> {...}
```

you can add to `ListView` only Song-instance (can not add heirs of `Song.class`)

```
ListView<Song> songListView = new SongListView();
```

also you can not assign `SongListView` to generic reference of other heirs of  of `Song.class`

```
class LongSong extends Song {...}
ListView<LongSong> songListView = new SongListView(); //Incompatible types.
```

Comment: y -> "How Can I specify that the Generic Type T is to be a Song Object and no other object?"

Comment: my `class Foo extends Song` is a Song... (and is not a String, Integer, Socket, ...)

Comment: @josejuan - I think the author means that only ``Song``  class (without heirs) have to be used in ``SongListView``